# package:google_mobile_ads/src/ad_container.dart':Failed assertion: line 1022 pos 16: 'nativeTemplateStyle != null || factoryId != null': is not true

Tags: flutter, admob, native, ads, google-mobile-ads

I am trying to integrate admob native ads in a flutter news app showing List of News cards with a Native Advance Admob ad loaded after every 2 news cards. But app is giving error below.

error: 'package:google_mobile_ads/src/ad_container.dart':Failed assertion: line 1022 pos 16: 'nativeTemplateStyle != null || factoryId != null': is not true

Error Source:
https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter/blob/main/packages/google_mobile_ads/lib/src/ad_containers.dart#L1022

My Code:
https://gist.github.com/ayushkadbe/1faeaa22416ea236d46cd63743782759#file-newslist-dart

Please tell me where to find factoryId.